# Dynamic path as Object parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, dynamic-arrays, ionic-framework

I have an array which is a serie of object looking just like this one :

```
 $scope.dishList = [
   {    nameEnglish: 'onion soup', 
        nameLocal: 'soupe a loignon',
        description: 'xxxxx',
        region: 'vanitia',
        itemid: 'IT022',
        cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'IT',
        imageSource: '( "img/" + dish.cuisineTypeIsoCode + "/" + dish.itemid + "small.jpg")',

    }
    // some more similar objects

];
```

Every image name is constructed as follows" IT001small.jpg, IT002small.jpg etc and is stored in img/{{cuisineTypeIsoCode}}/img.pjg

I would like to include the path to the images in that array so I can then use this parameter in my HTML template with the {{dish.imageSource}} statement (see below)

```
    <article class="item_frame">
        <a class="" href="#"><img class="bookmark_icon" src="img\bookmark_plus_whitev3.png">
        </a>
        <img class="item_main_image" ng-src="{{dish.imageSource}}">
        <img class="item_icon_circled" src="img/dishiconv4orangecircled.png">
        <h1 class="item_name_english">{{dish.nameEnglish}}</h1>
        <h2 class="item_name_local_language">{{dish.nameLocal}}</h2>
        <p class="item_description ">{{dish.description}}</p>
        <div class="subcuisine_container_w_flag">
            <span class="subcuisine_text_in_dish_pages"> | {{dish.region}}</span>
            <img class="flag_in_dishpages" src="img/flag.png">
        </div>  
    </article><!--main article frame 1 -->
```

I have tried several things but could not get anything to work ... Any idea please ? 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exact answer but **Better Alternate Approach**, I think you can replace with following one:

```
<img class="item_main_image" ng-src="img/{{dish.cuisineTypeIsoCod}}/{{dish.itemid}}small.jpg">
```

Happy Helping!

Comment: oh  indeed, had not thought about this .. but does not work !

Comment: @lauWM this is the angular way - and it should work as expected, what error are you seeing while using this ? if image is available at correct constructed path as: img/{{dish.cuisineTypeIsoCod}}/{{dish.itemid}}small.jpg it shoud be displayed

Comment: works perfectly my bad, there was a syntax error , thanks a lot !